# Вопросительное предложение

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оформить фразу ( в плане пунктуации): **"Вы их видели - отца и сына?"** Или вместе тире надо ставить запятую? Или вообще надо оформить так: **"Вы их видели? Отца и сына"** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны два варианта:  (1)Вы их видели - отца и сына? (2)"Вы их видели, отца и сына? 
Выбор знака препинания можно отнести к  теме «Запятая или тире при обособлении пояснительных членов предложения, стоящих  в конце предложения».

А.  РАЗБЕРЕМ ПОХОЖИЕ ПРИМЕРЫ

Сравним два предложения:  (1) Осенние зори иные – хмурые, медленные. (2) Осенние зори иные, хмурые и медленные.  Обратим внимание на то, что однородный ряд с бессоюзной связью требует тире как более сильного знака, иначе семантика трех определений  не различается. Но если союз И объединяет два определения в одну фразу, то для понимания смысла хватает и запятой.

Б.  ВАРИАНТ С ЗАПЯТОЙ

Для предложения  «Вы видели Их, отца и сЫна?» подходит структура (2), то есть обособление   с помощью запятой. Но  такая структура предложения невыразительна, так как не дает возможности выделить слово «видели» логическим ударением.

В. АВТОРСКОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ ПРИ ИНВЕРСИИ МЕСТОИМЕНИЯ

И тогда мы делаем перестановку: «Вы их вИдели – отцА и сЫна?». Теперь, при инверсии  местоимения, пояснению можно придать присоединительный характер, требующий паузы и тире.  Такая  структура предложения  имеет определенные преимущества: слово «видели» становится ЛОГИЧЕСКИМ центром высказывания, а  также тоническим ударением выделяются слова  «отцА и сЫна». При отсутствии логического ударения применяем вариант с запятой:«Вы их видели,  отца и сына?». Таким образом, мы приходим к авторскому решению: эмоционально-экспрессивный вариант с тире или более спокойный вариант с запятой, что должно соответствовать общему стилю текста.

Г. ПАРЦЕЛЛЯЦИЯ

Парцелляция (деление высказывания на части) – это особый  прием, он применяется достаточно редко, при решении особых стилистических задач. Без необходимости им пользоваться не стоит.

Comment: София, спасибо Вам, что всегда отвечаете так развернуто! Значит все-таки возможны два варианта. Хотя с тире - предпочтительнее. Но если исходить из внешнего вида диалога, то, как мне кажется, этих тире будет слишком много. А как Вы думаете? 



–Вы их видели – отца и сына? 

–Нет.



Хотя, конечно, главное не внешний вид текста, а его суть, грамотность и т.д. Но эти тире в ряд меня немного смущают...

Comment: И  третий  вариант  возможен.  С  двумя  вопросительными.  При  этом  изменится  интонация  говорящего.

Comment: Ммарина, я уже не думаю, что тире предпочтительнее, можно остановиться и на запятой. Такое впечатление, что здесь и СМЫСЛОВЫЕ оттенки важны. Паузу, обозначающую тире, можно рассматривать как пропущенное пояснение "я имею в виду", если собеседнику не совсем очевидно, о ком идет речь. А вариант с запятой используется как базовый, когда это  достаточно ясно.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, тогда на нем и остановлюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предпочёл ваш второй вариант с точкой в конце последнего предложения, либо с восклицательным знаком (в зависимости от эмоций вопрошающего). Объясню. Когда человек ищет кого-то, ему кажется, что окружающие знают о его проблемах, поэтому и спрашивает  вкратце, а когда видит немой вопрос в глазах собеседника, поясняет. Вот и выходит, что второе предложение скорее ответ, чем вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!